# Does C Code enjoy the Go GC's fragmentation prevention strategies?

Tags: go, garbage-collection, swig, cgo, virtual-address-space

**Corrected the false implications:**

Golang's GC does virtual address space <s>defragmentation</s> fragmentation-prevention strategies, which enables a program to run for a very long time (if not ever).

But it seems C code (cgo or SWIG) has no means of <s>having it's memory pointers updated in case they get moved elsewhere.</s> getting benefit from these strategies.

1. Is it true? Won't C code get benefit from Golang's virtual address space <s>defragmentation</s> fragmentation-prevention, and will finally get fragmentation?
2. If that's false, how?
3. Also, what happens to any DLL code loaded by C code (e.g. Windows DLLs) ?

**(The question is updated to correct my wrong assumptions)**

Comment: Where did you get the impression that the Go GC does defragmentation?

Comment: I'm interesting to hear what exactly is "virtual address space defragmentation".

Comment: Oh, may be you mean Go's GC is compacting? Then no, currently (v1.10) and before it is not compacting. The runtime maintains several regions to allocate objects of different size classes; these regions are called "spans", and a particular span goes away only if it has no in-use objects in it. But AFAIK presently the GC does not move objects across (same-sized) spans.

Comment: First of all, it's a systems' programming language and is used to write server things, which have to be able to run for several days with heavy work, and are not to be regularly terminated and re-executed. Without a proper (full) garbage collection that includes defragmentation, Golang would be garbage for systems programming and writing servers. Second, I'm sure I've read somewhere, and am searching to find it. :)

Comment: "Defragmentation" would imply moving live pointers, which the GC does not do. Go relies on an allocation scheme that results in very little fragmentation in the first place. I don't understand how C would somehow benefit if the Go GC did do this, since C doesn't use GC (and it uses different allocators to begin with. tcmalloc is similar to the Go allocator, though Go has diverged quite a bit)

Comment: «Golang would be garbage for systems programming and writing servers» —
 yeah, [sure, no one uses Go to write production systems: it has toy GC!](https://twitter.com/brianhatfield/status/634166123605331968?lang=en) ;-)

Comment: Thanks you both for correcting me. I searched and there are no traces of "the Go GC doing defragmentation", and you seem to be better informed than me on this subject, so I guess what I'd read must've been "Go programs' not having fragmentation problem". My apologies. So now my questions about C code turn into "Would C code enjoy GC's virtual address space fragmentation prevention and how and what happens to loaded DLLs?". I'll try to re-write them(or should I post them again?).

Comment: @SmallBoy: as I mentioned, that is up to the allocator, and in C you get to choose your allocator, it has nothing to do with C the language itself.

Comment: @JimB: Thank you very much for mentioning and also for trying again kindly. :) Sorry for my ambiguity. I meant, using such C code defeats one of the essential benefits of using Go in the first place, which is a vital feature for writing server things, but meanwhile nobody warns about using cgo or SWIG. I mean I couldn't believe that the much popular and officially recommended methods of using C code in Go, make the compiled program lose one of the Go's most important achievements. So I gotta say goodbye to using C code and dynamically loading DLL's in my server, do I?

Comment: @SmallBoy, put together my thoughts on your last comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you might be confusing things on multiple levels here.

First, calling into C in a production-grade Go code is *usually* a no-go right from the start: *it is slow; as slow as making a system call* — as for the most part it really works as a system call: one need to switch from Go stack to C stack and have the OS thread which happened to be executing the Go code which made the `cgo` call to be locked to that thread even if something on the C side blocks.

That is not to say you must avoid calling out to C, but this means you need to think this through up front *and measure.* May be setting up a pool of worker goroutines onto which to fan out the tasks which need to make C calls.

Second, your memory concerns might be well unfounded; let me explain.

Fragmenting *virtual* memory should be a non-issue on contemporary systems
usually used to run Go programs (I mean `amd64` and the like).
That is pretty much because allocating virtual memory does not force the OS
to actually allocate *physical* memory pages — the latter happens only
when the virtual memory gets *used* (that is, accessed at an address
happening to point into an allocated virtual memory region).
So, want you or not, you *do* have that physical memory fragmentation problem
anyway, and it is getting sorted out
at the OS and CPU level using multiple-layered address translation
tables (and TLB-caches).

Third, you appear to be falling into a common trap of *speculating* about
how things will perform under load instead of writing a highly simplified
model program and inspecting how it behaves under the estimated production
load. That is, you *think* a problem with allocating C memory *will occur*
and then fancy the whole thing will not work.

I would say your worries are unfounded — given the amount of production
code written in C and C++ and working under hardcore loads.

And finally, C and C++ programmers tred the pathways to high-performance
memory management long time ago. A typical solution is using custom
pool allocators for the objects which exhibit the most 
allocation/deallocation churn under the typical load. With this approach,
the memory allocated on your C side is mostly stable for the lifetime
of your program.

**TL;DR**

Write a model program, put the estimated load on it and see how it behaves.
*Then* analyze, what the problems with the memory are, if any, and
only then start attacking them.

Comment: (First) Thanks much. I didn't know it. I'm trying to compensate interpretation for calling dynamically compiled DLL code. Your comment is of much of use to me. (Second) Thanks. I'm well aware of MMU design and the memory-on-demand approach. I read a couple of times but I didn't get the relation between my concerns about virtual address space fragmentation, and physical address space fragmentation. (Third) Thanks much. You're right but my concerns are because I thought a server thing should normally never ever ever need re-execution, so I wanted to make sure it is 100% fragmentation-tolerant.

Comment: A few months ago, I came back to it after some time, and then I understood the second part as well, and chose it as the answer. Now, I also better realize the importance of the third part, and I find it absolutely true about me. I wish I had better embraced that before. I like to appreciate your opinion and thank you again. (At last I found Go incompetent in terms of flexibility and compiled size, and switched to C).

Answer (score -2):

It depends.

The memory which the C code needs can be allocated by Go and it's pointer be passed to C code. In this case, C code will get benefit from Go's fragmentation-prevention strategies.

The same goes for DLL code, so if DLL functions don't allocate their working memory on their own, this can be done for them as well.

Comment: Down-voters should describe their thoughts, 'cause I can't understand what they think about what I thought which they have problem with.